# Raspberry Pi Won't Login

Tags: pi-2

This is not the "it's not displaying when I type in my password issue", I'm a noob but not that big of one. I have my Pi boot to the graphical user interface and it displays the login screen, I type in my username and password and it acts like its about to accept it, the screen goes black and suddenly I'm back at the login screen. Any advice?

Update: I over rode gui login and did it through the terminal. When I did startx instead of a GUI it boots a black screen.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you've had a 'permissions' issue somewhere - try this:
`sudo -i ; cd /home ; shopt -s dotglob ; chown -R capitan:capitan capitan` (or whatever your username is..)
This sets user to root, sets a shell option to not ignoring hidden files, then recursively sets you as owner of every file in your home directory.
A bit "shotgun" but sorts out all the permissions! 9 times out of 10 fixes it when I do this - usually by running something `sudo` when I shouldn't have.